# Expose Google compute engine or Kubernetes through HTTPS

Tags: spring-boot, https, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, devops

I have a spring boot application that i want to deploy on google compute engine or kubernetes and i want to expose it through https instead of http.
I want to do this because i have an angular frontend that is deployed on google app engine and it needs to access the api through https instead of http.

The api is accessible through port 8080 and it works if i use http. How can i exspose the api through https, can i use a load balancer with https to redirect all incoming traffic to http?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think the SSL certificate is the key for both (GCE and KE). You must to set a certificate for each option.

On Kubernetes Engine you could deploy the application with a Load Balancer and install a SSL certificate on it. Then you have to modify your ingress configuration to use the SSl certificate. Of course this process is too large to explain here, but you can find the details here [1], to find details about Load Balancer ingress configuration here [2]

For GCE you will require to set a SSL certificate on instance or using a Load balancer. Take a look to this GCP documentation that explain it [3]

[1] https://estl.tech/configuring-https-to-a-web-service-on-google-kubernetes-engine-2d71849520d

[2] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#remarks

[3] https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#https-and-ssl